# Hyperlinking database content

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

I'm building a database-driven gaming fansite and I want to be able to hyperlink mentions of items and other words that have their own page. For example, assume this is a page.

> Item Name
>
> This is a description of the item being pulled from the database. It can be combined with Item2 and
>   Item3 to make Item4.

I would like to hyperlink Item2, Item3 and Item4 to their respective pages so that a user can navigate through the website more efficiently rather than having to type each name into the search bar manually.

I know that this can be achieved by inserting HTML into the description cell and have the browser to output it, but besides the obvious security risk of outputting unsantiised HTML, it would also be incredibly tedious to do this for each item and the table could begin to look rather ugly as it gets filled with anchor tags.

Nevertheless, I've seen such functionality on other websites and I'm wondering what's the safest and/or most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: So you'r'e suggesting having SQL retrieve all item names and then scan each one against each word of the string and implementing anchors for each match? If so that would seem inefficient unless I misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 0):

Create file like item.php.

```
if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {

    $item_name = $_GET['name'];
    //Your code like fetching from database WHERE name LIKE $item_name
    //And also printing your description with the hyperlinks to the  actualy item from $_GET['name']

}
```

If you have not so much different items you can add the achors with str_replace. Heres an example.

```
<?php
$text = "This is a description of the item being pulled from the database. It can be combined with Item2 and Item3 to make Item4.";

$item_names = array("Item2", "Item3", "Item4");

foreach($item_names as $item_name) {
    $text = str_replace($item_name, "<a href='item.php?name=".$item_name."'>".$item_name."</a>", $text);
}

echo $text;
?>
```

`$item_names` must be a array with all you item names.

And Hyperlinks like:

> This is a description of the item being pulled from the database. It can >be combined with Item2 (item.php?name=item2) and Item3 >(item.php?name=item3) to make Item4 (item.php?name=item4).`

Comment: I already have an item page which displays items based a valid _get but I don't understand how `(item.php?name=item2)` becomes a descriptive hyperlink? Surely it would just print that as it is and not simply as "item1"?

Comment: Because you can use the WHERE clause in your SQL to geht the information of the item. There you can distinguish which information will presented. Like `SELECT * FROM items WHERE name like $_GET['name']

Comment: I already have such functionality, I just don't understand how you're creating the hyperlinks in the description without using anchors?

Comment: How much different items do you have in your database?